# Integrate blink taskbar in Caliburn IWindowManager interface

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

in order to blink taskbar, I found the following code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5118285/1830639, which give me 2 extensions methods that I care about:

```
window.FlashWindow(5);
window.StopFlashingWindow();
```

I'm creating some sort of chat messenger, and there are two interesting scenarios:

1. Focus opened window when user clicks to chat an already opened chat.
2. Blink opened window when a message arrives to an already opened chat.

The **1.** I've accomplish with the following (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14765848/1830639):

```
 public class MetroWindowManager : WindowManager
{
    private IDictionary<WeakReference, WeakReference> windows = new Dictionary<WeakReference, WeakReference>();

    public override void ShowWindow(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null)
    {
        NavigationWindow navWindow = null;

        if (Application.Current != null && Application.Current.MainWindow != null)
        {
            navWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as NavigationWindow;
        }

        if (navWindow != null)
        {
            var window = CreatePage(rootModel, context, settings);
            navWindow.Navigate(window);
        }
        else
        {
            var window = GetExistingWindow(rootModel);
            if (window == null)
            {
                window = CreateWindow(rootModel, false, context, settings);
                windows.Add(new WeakReference(rootModel), new WeakReference(window));
                window.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                window.Focus();
            }
        }

    }
```

**ChatManager**:

```
 public class ChatManager : IChatManager
{
    private readonly IChatWindowSettings chatWindowSettings;
    private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;
    private IDictionary<WeakReference, WeakReference> chats;

    public ChatManager(IChatWindowSettings chatWindowSettings, IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        this.chatWindowSettings = chatWindowSettings;
        this.windowManager = windowManager;

        chats = new Dictionary<WeakReference, WeakReference>();
    }

    public void OpenFor(Contact contact)
    {
        var settings = chatWindowSettings.Create();
        var viewModel = CreateOrGetViewModel(contact);
        windowManager.ShowWindow(viewModel, null, settings);
    }

    private ChatViewModel CreateOrGetViewModel(Contact contact)
    {
        ChatViewModel viewModel;
        if (!chats.Any(c => c.Key.IsAlive && c.Key.Target == contact))
        {
            viewModel = new ChatViewModel(contact);
            chats.Add(new WeakReference(contact), new WeakReference(viewModel));
        }
        else
        {
            var chat = chats.Single(d => d.Key.Target == contact).Value;
            if (!chat.IsAlive)
            {
                viewModel = new ChatViewModel(contact);
                chats.Add(new WeakReference(contact), new WeakReference(viewModel));
            }
            else
            {
                viewModel = chat.Target as ChatViewModel;
            }
        }

        return viewModel;
    }
```

As you can see, I'm relying on ***IWindowManager*** interface. Now for the **2.** I thought of implementing an extension method on *IWindowManager* *Blink()*, however in the extension method I don't have access to the *WeakReferences* (*windows* variable) I've created in the **MetroWindowManager**:

```
 public void MessageFor(Contact contact, IChatMessage message)
    {
        var viewModel = CreateOrGetViewModel(contact);
        windowManager.Blink(viewModel);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. Going to share the code in case somebody is interested.

I've created my own `IWindowManager` that extends `Caliburn.Micro.IWindowManager`. The catch was how to get the **same instance** for both interfaces:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extends Caliburn.Micro.IWindowManager functionalities, such as blinking windows.
/// </summary>
public interface IWindowManager : Caliburn.Micro.IWindowManager
{
    void Blink(object rootModel);
}
```

**MetroWindowManager**:

```
public class MetroWindowManager : WindowManager, Communicator.Core.IWindowManager
{
    private IDictionary<WeakReference, WeakReference> windows = new Dictionary<WeakReference, WeakReference>();

    public void Blink(object rootModel)
    {
        //have access to 'windows' dictionary
    }
```

**SimpleInjector Bootstrapper**:

```
var windowManager = new MetroWindowManager();
        container = new Container();
        container.Register<Communicator.Core.IWindowManager>(()=> windowManager);
        container.Register<Caliburn.Micro.IWindowManager>(() => windowManager);
```

Whenever I have a dependency on my `IWindowManager` or `Caliburn.Micro.IWindowManager`, IoC passes the same instance.